# Making <img> inline with div element inside a div block

Tags: html, css

I'm developing my website, and currently crafting the navigation bar.

The fiddle below represents the navbar when the screen size is less than 800px, I want my logo to be on the left hand side and the toggle navigation button to be on the right.

I have tried to put properties `display: inline;` to `.logo img` and `.navbar-toggle` but it doesn't work.

Why am I wrong there? And how can I fix it?

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbHB4/9720/

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://www.sherkspear.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/jsfiddle.png"/>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button> 
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.navbar-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.logo img {
  padding: 9px 10px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: no need inline to logo but you need inline to its container (and better inline-block)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Sure, I'm going to modify my question! Really sorry for that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have modified you code and added `display:flex` to the header and removed unwanted code. hope this help:)

```css
.navbar-header {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.logo{
  width: 100%;
}
.logo img {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://www.sherkspear.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/jsfiddle.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-toggle">
    <button type="button"  data-toggle="collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use `display: flex;` as the perfectly working answer from **Qubis**, you could use this css and go with the `float` approach ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbHB4/9735/)):

```
    .navbar-toggle, .logo {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .logo img {
      padding: 9px 10px;
      border: 5px solid blue;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   }
   .navbar-toggle {
      padding: 9px 10px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      background-color: green;
      border: 5px solid red;
      border-radius: 4px;
   }
```

If you want the toggle button on the left side, just change the order in the HTML. So that the logo comes first in the DOM and then the button

Comment: The problem is that I want the image to be on the left of the button. This code render beautifully but doesn't solve the problem :D

Comment: if you want the toggle button on the left side, just change the order in the HTML. So that the logo comes first in the DOM and then the button: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 1):

Change .navbar-header to:

```
.navbar-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

EDIT:

Use flex-direction if you don't want to edit HTML.
Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The problem is that I want the image to be on the left of the button. This code render beautifully but doesn't solve the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

USe media-query or bootstrap.
Some example your code:

```
@media (max-width:799px){
  .navbar-toggle{float:right}
  .logo{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
  }
  .navbar-header{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```